# React component creates new component on scroll causing it to call server infinitely

Tags: reactjs, infinite-loop, use-effect

The issue that I experience on React is the following:
I have a div which contains some data.
[image: that the user selected]

This div can get really large and I want to hide it on scroll down so that the cards can take up the space. To that I've used an npm package that does just that via:

[image: Component that helps hiding my div on scroll down]

Everything works just fine but the issue comes, when I scroll up, I get an infinite amount of useEffect calls from IngredientsListHorizontal component until I scroll back up to the initial position.
I want to mention that I only have a dependency on the useEffect inside my component and that is:
[image: my component useEffect]

Even though it has only one dependency which is not changing when I scroll up, I get an infinite amount of calls. If I put a breakpoint there, I am not hitting that, like my component is re-rendered somewhere behind the scenes.
What should I do? Any ideas ?

This is what I see under network when the scroll up happens, (or if I stop the scroll and don't reach the starting point):
[image: fetch]

Comment: Please provide actual code, or even better - sandbox to play with. Do not use screenshots for code, they are unworkable for us here

Comment: what does `open` used in the useEffect dependency array look like? From what you have provided, Looks like this could happen either because a) Your component is unmounting/mounting for some reason, or b) open reference is changing (or value is changing) therefore firing the useEffect calling your API. From your title, could be option a. We need more code.